# Django: follow relations backwards

Tags: python, django, orm

Hey, I have models like this:

```
class Galleries(models.Model):
  creation_date = models.DateTimeField()
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
  gallery_type = models.ForeignKey(Categories)

class Categories(models.Model):
  handle = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Values(models.Model):
  category = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
  language = models.CharField(max_length=7)
  category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And now, I just want to reach the values of categories by starting from Galleries. For example: `galleries = Galleries.objects.get(id=1)`. And now I want to reach somehow the values by using this "galleries" object... To get values with specific language would be much more better... I miss skills in Django ORM, so if you can, please point me to some docs or give some code example. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
galleries = Galleries.objects.get(id=1)
values = galleries.gallery_type.values_set.filter(language='language')
```

Interestingly, you used the exact wording that the docs use to refer to the related field lookups. I always found the definition strange to the gut, maybe because they put it in quotes.

> FOLLOWING RELATIONSHIPS "BACKWARD"

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: Thanks man! I was really close to that and you corrected my logic a little! Thanks!

Comment: The link is currently broken.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the select_related method of objects so you reduce the number of queries you are making. [select_related](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

```
gallery = Galleries.objects.select_related().get(id=1)
```

You can set a related name for the Values model in the category fk:

```
class Values(models.Model):
  category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, related_name="categories")
  language = models.CharField(max_length=7)
  category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

now you can get your list of values for a specific language by doing

```
values = gallery.gallery_type.categories.filter(language="language")
```

Comment: Sigh. `select_related` has no effect on backwards relationships. And you don't need to set a `related_name` to get access to the reverse relationship - if you don't set one, a default is created, as Yuji shows.

Comment: The select_related will have an effect on the fk to Categories, if im not mistaken? And the related_name just makes the reverse relationship more readable, imho. But yes Yuji's answer was complete using the default.