# How to get reverse relationship in Django's ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

I usually tend to avoid giving such explicit examples, but in this case it's necessary.

I have 5 entities:

1. Student
2. Group
3. StudentGroup
4. CourseGroup
5. Course (not relevant -- for completeness purpose only)

`StudentGroup` represents students who are part of a group. A `CourseGroup` is a course the whole group is taking part in.

I want to get all students that are part of a `Group` and are taking part in a specific `Course`. So far, I've only managed to get all students in a group:

```
students = Student.objects.filter(studentgroup=1)
```

Not sure why I can say `studentgroup=1` but it's fortunate. However there's no `studentgroupcourse=1` :) Any help?

**Edit**: My models are: http://pastebin.com/07z1iEcw

Comment: For reference, I've seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212463/django-follow-relations-backwards but it doesn't look like it applies to me. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Please post your model definitions, and if that is not possible at least post the types of relationships (ForeignKey, ManyToMany) between each model in your list

Comment: @dm03514 updated question with my models. I believe I adapted your answer to what I need: `studentgroup__group__coursegroup__course`. Didn't know that you can go through relationships with two underscores. Will accept your answer for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASSUMING `CourseGroup` has a foreignkey to `StudentGroup` and a foreignKey to a `Course`

`Student.objects.filter(studentgroup=1, studentgroup__coursegroup__course=your_course)`